# Implementing jQuery into an Angular Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a bit of jQuery that I wrote for a fancy little here state.  I want to take the code that I wrote, and implement it into the new AngularJS site that I'm making.  I'm just not really sure where to start.

I think the best thing would be to make a Directive, but it needs to be triggered on click.

The JS:

```
var moveHereState = function(oldPos) {
  var oldPos = oldPos;
  var newPos = $('.active').position();
  if(newPos.left < oldPos.left) {
    $('.here-state').css("-webkit-transform", "scaleX( 1)");
  } else {
    $('.here-state').css("-webkit-transform", "scaleX( -1)");
  }
  newPos = newPos.left +"px";
  $('.here-state').css('left', newPos);
};

$('a').on('click', function() {
  var oldPos = $('.active').position();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  moveHereState(oldPos);
});

moveHereState($('.active').position());
```

You can see this in action here: http://codepen.io/Pink401k/pen/sxljF?editors=001

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve what you want. Nowadays, I would probably choose a different route (e.g. using a directive controller and `require`-ing from the children), but I tried to implement it as "new-comer-friendly" as possible.

---

#### The logic

- I chose to attach a directive to the parent container, i.e. the `<ul>`.
- The container is responsible for finding the little rabit thingy (I call it *marker*) and the "positions" (i.e. `<a>` elements), based on predefined selectors/classes.
- The container is also responsible for attaching listeners to the "positions", remove the listeners in case of "destruction" (e.g. removing the element) and initializing the marker's position.

---

#### The code

```
app.directive('hereStateContainer', function () {
    var activeClass    = 'active';
    var activeSelector = '.' + activeClass;
    var markerSelector = '.here-state';

    function moveMarker(container, oldPos) {
        var newPos = container.find(activeSelector).position();
        var marker = container.find(markerSelector);

        var scale = ((!oldPos || (newPos.left > oldPos.left)) ? '-' : '') + '1';
        marker.css({
            'left': newPos.left + 'px',
            '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(' + scale + ')'
        });
    }
    
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function hereStateContainerPostLink(scope, elem) {
            function hereStateContainerOnClick() {
                var activeElem = elem.find(activeSelector);
                var oldPos;
                
                if (activeElem) {
                    oldPos = activeElem.position();
                    activeElem.removeClass(activeClass);
                }

                $(this).addClass(activeClass);
                moveMarker(elem, oldPos);
            }

            elem.find('a').on('click', hereStateContainerOnClick);
            scope.$on('$destroy', function hereStateContainerOnDestroy() {
                elem.find('a').off('click', hereStateContainerOnClick);
            });

            moveMarker(elem);
        }
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/xov2tz8u/)**.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!  It was definitely a little past my experience level with Angular, so I really appreciate the help.

As a note for anyone else that is interested in this, the <li>s can't be positioned relatively, or things seem to break :)